# Add footer to layout with two fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm using two layouts with fragments, one for portait mode and one for landscape.  I need to add a sticky footer to both layouts, and I've successfully added it to the portrait layout, but when I use similar code for the landscape layout it's not working.  If I set the `layout_width` of the fragments to `0dp`, I see neither fragment, if I set the `layout_width` to `wrap_content` or `fill_parent`, the fragments overlaps each other.

This is what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>
    <!-- Footer -->     
    <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/footer" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     />
    <!-- Footer -->

    <fragment android:name="com.app.listing1"
            android:id="@+id/fragment1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/footer"            
     />

    <fragment android:name="com.app.listing2"
            android:id="@+id/fragment2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/footer"            
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT

I've gotten a little closer to what I want.  If I put a set width on fragment1, then I get what I'm looking for, but that is, obviously, not ideal.  For some reason, setting layout_width="wrap_content" on the layout of both fragments, as well as the layouts within each fragment, results in the first fragment taking over the entire screen:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>
    <!-- Footer -->     
    <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/footer" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     />
    <!-- Footer -->

    <fragment android:name="com.app.listing1"
            android:id="@+id/fragment1"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/footer"            
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/fragment2"
     />

    <fragment android:name="com.app.listing2"
            android:id="@+id/fragment2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/footer"            
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fragment1"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

The fragments overlap each other because you did not align them in your RelativeLayout. If you want them to be arranged horizontal so use `layout_toRightOf` or `layout_toLeftOf`

Comment: Hmmm, that didn't work.  I added android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" to the first fragment and android:layout_alignParentRight="true" to the second, but they are still overlapping

Comment: Sorry I meant left_of/right_of. If you want to layout your fragment2 to right of fragment1 you add `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fragment1"` to your fragment2 and set your fragment1 to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Comment: Ugh, still didn't work.  Now it only shows fragment1 over the entire screen.  Do you know if the content within the fragments will effect it?  I have RelativeLayouts with layout_width and layout_height set to fill_parent inside of each fragment.  I have such a mental block when it comes to working with Android layouts.

Comment: But your assumption is right :). When you set your fragment1 to `wrap_content` your widht/height will be as big as it's content. You set your content (children) to `fill_parent` so your fragment1 "wraps `fill_parent`" and so it's as big as your screen is. Set the content to `wrap_content` too

Comment: No luck. :(  I've set every layout I can think of to wrap_content.  I'm going to tinker around with it some more, because there's probably something simple I'm missing.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe a view of your fragment1 takes up the full screen (e.g. a TextView with a long String). If you can't solve it post the two fragment layouts

Comment: Checkout the edits I made to the OP.  I'm getting a little closer if I put a set width on the first fragment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9830/discussion-between-207-and-kris-b)

Comment: Hey, I figured it out.  Adding layout_weight="50" gave me both fragments on the screen.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nevermind, that didn't work.  Ugh, I feel like working with Android layouts is like that one definition of insanity, doing the same thing over and over and expecting different results.

Comment: This is quit confusing here talking in comments. You can join the chat and we'll see what the problem is